# Getting "TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object" In my function. I am trying to print the MAC address to the screen

Tags: python, typeerror

My get_current_mac function:

```
def get_current_mac(interface):
    ifconfig_result = subprocess.check_output(["ifconfig", interface])
    mac_address_search_result = re.search(r"\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w", ifconfig_result)

    if mac_address_search_result:
        return mac_address_search_result.group(0)
    else:
        print("[-] Could not read MAC address.")
```

I am then wanting to print the result to the screen:

```
options = get_arguments()
current_mac = get_current_mac(options.interface)
print("Current MAC address is: " + str(current_mac))
```

The entire error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./MAC_changer.py", line 38, in <module>
    current_mac = get_current_mac(options.interface)
  File "./MAC_changer.py", line 30, in get_current_mac
    mac_address_search_result = re.search(r"\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w", ifconfig_result)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/re.py", line 183, in search
    return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object
```

line 38 is: `options = get_arguments()`

line 30 is: `mac_address_search_result = re.search(r"\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w", ifconfig_result)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert a **byte-like** object into a **string**, this can be done using `decode` method:

```
ifconfig_result = ifconfig_result.decode('utf-8')
```

In [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606191/convert-bytes-to-a-string) you can read more about converting bytes to string